# When should we use LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE

Tags: android, opengl-es

After reading on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html , my understanding on 3 different type of layering techniques are (Assume the device has GPU)

- **LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE** - *Draw* is performed by software on software's off-screen bitmap memory. Software's off-screen bitmap will then transferred to GPU. GPU *render* the bitmap on screen.
- **LAYER_TYPE_NONE** - GPU will *draw* directly on screen.
- **LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE** - *Draw* is performed by GPU on GPU's off-screen bitmap memory. GPU's off-screen bitmap will then *render* to screen by GPU.

### When to use LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE

My understanding certain *draw* operation isn't supported by GPU like `setShadowLayer`. Hence, we need to switch to `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, so that *draw* will be performed by software.

However, since there's software's off-screen bitmap memory transferred to GPU operation, things may appear slower.

### When to use LAYER_TYPE_NONE

I think this is the default settings in most of the devices. So, I assume we should use this technique most of the time.

### When to use LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE

I have no idea when to use this technique. Any example will be very much appreciated, on when we should apply `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` technique.

p/s Also, my understanding on **LAYER_TYPE_...** may appear wrong. Kindly correct me, if you find any mistake. Thank you.

Comment: LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE: The view is rendered in hardware into a hardware texture ,if the application is hardware accelerated. If the application is not hardware accelerated,this layer type behaves the same as LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 4):

**When to use LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE**

When I want to draw a text that cutout the parent view (allowing you to see through it) I use:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
```

For example in my custom view:

```
init {
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
}

private val textPaint = TextPaint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    textSize = size
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    createTextLayout(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec))
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
}

private fun createTextLayout(textWidth: Int) {
    textLayout = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        StaticLayout.Builder
                .obtain(text, 0, text.length, textPaint, textWidth)
                .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)
                .build()
    } else {
        StaticLayout(text, textPaint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1f, 0f, true)
    }
}

...

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas?.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, width / 2f, circlePaint)

    canvas?.withTranslation(
            x = width / 2f - textLayout.width / 2f,
            y = height / 2f - textLayout.height / 2f
    ) {
        textLayout.draw(canvas)
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

And without setting LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you're doing that in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Basically its like a drawing cache.  if your  custom view is expensive to render/draw but the content doesn't change too much often then i'd use the flag. otherwise your just stressing out the device to cache for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should use most of the times LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE as it is more efficient.
But must take into account that **not all Canvas Drawing Operations** are supported with **LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE** on specific API levels. So, you may need to switch to **LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE** if you need to do some unsupported drawing by hardware acceleration.

List of draw support operations across API levels: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#unsupported)

Next link describes extensively hardware acceleration, which will hint you when to use it or not: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)